# Array in two methods

Tags: java, methods

```
 import java.util.Scanner;



 public class ld11 {


public static void firstMethod(int[] A) {
        int size = A.length;
        int equal[] = new int[size];
        int less[] = new int[size];
        int B[] = new int[size];
        int i,j,k;
        for(i=0; i<size; i++){
            for(j=0;j<size;j++){
            if(A[i]==A[j]){equal[i]++;}
            else if(A[i]>A[j]){less[i]++;}
            }}
        for(i=0;i<size;i++){k=less[i];for(j=0;j<equal[i];j++){B[k+j]=A[i];}}
        System.arraycopy(B, 0, A,0, A.length);

    }

private static void sellaMethod(int[] A){
    int t;

    t=(int) (Math.log(A.length)/Math.log(2)-1);

    int[] h = new int[t];
    h[0]=1;
    for(int i=1;i<h.length;i++)
        h[i]=2*h[i-1]+1;
    t--;

    while(t>=0){
        int inc=h[t];
        t--;
        for(int i=inc;i<A.length;i++){
            int temp=A[i];
            int j=i-inc;
            while (j>=0 && A[j]>temp) {
                A[j+inc]=A[j];
                j=j-inc;
            }
            A[j+inc]=temp;
        }
    }
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("1st task");
        System.out.print("Method(1/2): ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
            x = sc.nextInt();
        else {System.out.println("input-output-error");
            sc.close();
            return;}
        if(x!=1 && x!=2){
            System.out.println("input-output-error");
            return;}
        System.out.print("Count: ");
        int y;
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
            y = sc.nextInt();
        else {
            System.out.println("input-output-error");
            sc.close();
            return;}
        int []A = new int[y];
        System.out.println("Items:");
        int i = 0;
        do {if(sc.hasNextInt()){
            int z = sc.nextInt();
            A[i]=z;
            i++;}
        else{System.out.println("input-output-error");sc.close();return;}} while(i<y); 
        sc.close();

        System.out.println("Sorted:");
        if(x==1){firstMethod(A);}
        else if(x==2){sellaMethod(A);}
        for(i=0;i<y;i++){System.out.print(A[i]+" ");}
    }
```

The user needs to choose which method it wants to use then write how many numbers and then write them, and programme sorts numbers in a way which is described in the method. With first method everything is okay, but with second shows errors :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

```
at ld11.sellaMethod(ld11.java:26) (h[0]=1; in this row))

at ld11.main(ld11.java:79)    (else if(x==2){sellaMethod(A);}  in this row
```

As you can see it is Shell sort method.
Could you please help?

Comment: This code is quite unreadable. For example. all this in one line: `for(i=0;i<size;i++){k=less[i];for(j=0;j<equal[i];j++){B[k+j]=A[i];}}`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in line `t=(int) (Math.log(A.length)/Math.log(2)-1);`

If array has length less than `6` then `t` will be zero. So you'll create array with zero lenght. It's a bug. Probably you need some checks, probably another formula. Anyway, you have to review code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, your problem is your formula for getting the length of your `h` array.

A simple fix is just change this line:

```
t = (int) (Math.log(A.length) / Math.log(2) - 1);
```

to:

```
t = A.length;
```

as all you want is the new array to be same length as the initial array.